# Jquery: calculate value on blur event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do some live calculation on my form, please have a look at form...

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="product1" class="num"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="product2" class="num" />
<input type="text" value="0" name="product3" class="num"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="cost" class="cost"/>
```

And jquery code...

```
$(function() {
var cost = 0;
$('.num').blur(function(){
cost+= parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$('.cost').val(cost);
});
```

But its not working, please help thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the line which updates the value of the cost field inside your blur event handler:

**UPDATE**
There is also a problem with the logic by using this method where amending values will cause the total to constantly be added to, I've amended the code to fix this problem:

```
$(function() {
    $('.num').live("blur", function(){
        var parentLI = $(this).closest("LI");
        var cost = 0;
        $(".num", parentLI).each(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (!isNaN(value) && value != "")
                cost+= parseFloat(value);
        })
        $('.cost').val(cost);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer, can it be worked on appended boxes using jquery? i think its not working, should i use live function?

Comment: or should i write a different function for that.

Comment: If you are appending boxes via jQuery, then as you say, use the live function: $(".num").live("blur", function() {...})

Comment: i am appending these fields... `$('#fields').append('<li><input type="text" name="1" class="num" /> <input type="text" name="2" class="num" /> <input type="text" name="total" class="total" /></li>');` on click add button, it can add upto 20 li. but its adding result of total of all .total inputs, which is incorrect.

Comment: Assuming you only want the .num fields contained in the current LI totalled, I have amended the code above to fix this problem

Answer (score 3):

Just move the `$('.cost').val(cost);` into the blur function, or it won't be run when the blur function is run, only when the page is loaded.

So this should work:

```
$(function() {
  var cost = 0;
  $('.num').blur(function(){
      cost+= parseFloat($(this).val());
      $('.cost').val(cost);
  });
});
```

Comment: can it be worked on appended boxes using jquery? i think its not working, should i use live function?

Comment: Use delegate or live to append boxes and use the same function. 
But as mentioned below. If you try to update one of the boxes with the code above, you are just adding the value on top of it. So you should sum all of them together every time, or store the current value on focus and subtract it before you add the new number.

Comment: see i am appending these fields... `$('#fields').append('<li><input type="text" name="1" class="num" /> <input type="text" name="2" class="num" /> <input type="text" name="total" class="total" /></li>');` on click add button, it can add upto 20 li.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use id and not name for your document elements and make them unique.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
  var cost = 0;
  $('.num').blur(function(){
     cost+= parseFloat($(this).value());
     $('.cost').value(cost);
  });
});
```

Note how it is easier to see the problem with indenting.  The changing of the cost fields value was not in the right place.

Comment: thanks for yours answer, can it be worked on appended boxes using jquery? i think its not working, should i use live function?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of jQuery to, the `$('.cost').val(cost);` never got called as it was written outside the blur event function..so the control never went there once it was in the function

```
$(function() {
var cost = 0;
$('.num').blur(function(){

//EDIT
$('.cost').val(parseFloat($('.cost').val())+parseFloat($(this).val()));

});
$('.cost').val(cost);
});
```

And also use the `value` attribute instead of `val` in HTML textbox..

Comment: thanks for yours answer, can it be worked on appended boxes using jquery? i think its not working, should i use live function?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use change(fn) instead of blur to avoid unneccessary calculations when the value wasn't changed. .keyup(fn) would allow you to do it as the user types as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for suggestion but using keyup function, its not giving correct results.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use 'val' instead of 'value'